# How to apply a mapping to a value in a Puppet/Ruby ERB template?

Tags: ruby, erb, puppet

I'm writing an ERB template (for a Puppet module) that gets passed an Hash like this:

```
{"stuff" => {"foo"=>"aaa", "bar"=>"ccc"},
 "other" => {"foo"=>"bbb", "bar"=>"ddd"}}
```

and I'm iterating over it in my templates producing rows of text:

```
<% @my_data.each_pair do |k, v| -%>
<%= k %> <%= v["foo"] %>:<%= v["bar"] %>
<% end -%>
```

Now I'd like to apply some mapping to the "foo" data with a second hash I'll pass to the template. In pseudocode:

```
mappings = {"aaa" => "something", "bbb" => "somethingelse"}
<% @my_data.each_pair do |k, v| -%>
<%= k %> <%= TRANSLATE_SOMEHOW(v["foo"], mappings) %>:<%= v["bar"] %>
<% end -%>
```

...in order to get "something" whenever the value was "aaa", and so on. I expect to get the original value if there is no corresponding key in the "mappings".

Doing that kind of thing in Puppet's language is probably possible (by extending it with some Ruby code) I think it is probably more appropriate in the ERB template, but I don't know how to do that and not knowing Ruby isn't helping me - tried google without much success.

I'm looking for code to achieve that in an ERB function or some pointers to relevant documentation for my RTFM pleasure.

EDIT:
for future readers, here's DigitalRoss' answer translated to my ERB example above:

```
<% @my_data.each_pair do |k, v| -%>
<%= k %> <%= mappings[v["foo"]] || v["foo"] %>:<%= v["bar"] %>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the erb stuff removed for clarity, this is what you want to do. (The `p()` function just prints its argument. You can try this in irb.)

```
@my_data.each do |k, v|
  f, b = v['foo'], v['bar']
  p(mappings[f] || f)
  p(mappings[b] || b)
end
```

Comment: Perfect, I ported it to my ERB template and it worked like a charm. Not knowing Ruby I was looking for some function/method while the (foo || bar) construct was enough... thank you.